# SQLAlchemy, without explicitly stating a rollback call, are the uncommited changes of the session automatically rolledback?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

For example this code:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

def myfunction(a):
   #somechanges in database
   if a == 2:
     return
   db.session.commit()

myfunction(2) # there were some changes here that were not committed neither rolled back
myfunction(4) # Here the changes were committed.
```

My question is, are the first changes committed along with the second changes in the second call?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you read [the tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#adding-and-updating-objects) you'll see that the session has a `dirty` property:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

def myfunction(a):
   #somechanges in database
   if a == 2:
     return
   db.session.commit()

myfunction(2) # there were some changes here that were not committed neither rolled back
print(db.session.dirty)
myfunction(4) # Here the changes were committed.
```

What does it tell you?

Answer (score 1):

The changes performed in the call to `myFunction(4)` will overwrite the changes performed in the call to `myFunction(2)`. This is the case for updating data, commits or not.

For adding rows and columns, there is no over-writing of data. Committing before the function call to `myFunction(4)` will not make a difference.